# Typescript - Binding element 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

I am reformatting my redux store to learn some typescript -- How can I define `type` as a string? It is the first key of the second parameter of the function below. The error reads: `Binding element 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

```
const changeState = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "set":
      return { ...state, ...rest };
    case "alert":
      return { ...state, toasts: [...state.toasts, rest] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the type of the object you are sending as a parameter

You can do something like this if you want to pass and object with type as string and another *rest* as something else

```
const changeState = (state = initialState, obj: { type: string, rest:object }) => {
  switch (obj.type) {
    case "set":
      return { ...state, ...obj.rest };
    case "alert":
      return { ...state, toasts: [...state.toasts, obj.rest] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```